# How is firing action points consumption calculated?

Tags: fallout-4

In below video, the guy has two guns with the same firing rate, but they both consume different action points in V.A.T.S.

So I am curious, what are the driving factors for AP consumption when firing?

Furthermore, can weapons mods affect how many APs are consumed?

Comment: Further on in the video the streamer shows how a different stock affects the APs his .308 uses, so the answer to your last question is a yes. Curious about the main question myself, though.

Comment: Related: [Are VATS shots considered “hip fire” for weapon mod purposes?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/243584/4797)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are weapons which have a special effect, like "Consumes 25% less AP in V.A.T.S Mode". However, these weapons are only obtainable from legendary enemies.

In my experience, the AP cost of a weapon are determined by the following things:

- Weapon mods which start with light (less AP cost) or heavy (more AP cost)
- Fire rate (higher fire rate needs more AP)
- Sights (Scope needs more AP, while reflex needs less AP)
- Stock type (Short stock needs less AP)
- Accuracy (the more accurate a weapon is, the more AP it needs)

Against contrary believe, the weight of a weapon does NOT affect the AP usage of it.

Comment: (Weight affects ADS time, though, so unless you're doing a VATS build, make sure to take this into account while crafting.)

Comment: @zpletan Whats ADS time?

Comment: ADS stands for Aim Down Sights.  The time it takes for your gun to go from hip to readied sights.

Comment: Maybe I'm reading this wrong, but the fire rate note seems backward. I expect a fast firing weapon to use less AP per shot.

Comment: Wait, didn't you say light mods reduce AP cost but then you say weight doesn't affect AP usage. Which is it? In my experience, lighter weapons do use less AP in general.

Comment: @ChrisH. Well, yes and no. The weight itself does not affect the AP Usage, but the mod does. It's just another effect of it to decrease the weapons weight, but the AP cost are not directly tied to the weight.